# accessing imported XML element attribute with a given namespace in a JSP

Tags: jsp, xpath, jstl, expression

So I have done my research on here but was not able to find a suitable answer. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I know there have been similar questions but not quite exactly my issue.

I am importing an rss feed in jstl like so:

```
<c:import url="http://urltoRSSfeed" var="rssFeed" />
```

Once I have the feed, I am building the XML doc using DocumentBuilderFactory

```
<%  String xml = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("rssFeed");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
    Document doc = db.parse(is);
    pageContext.setAttribute("newXML",doc);%>
```

This is not the issue. I can access almost every element in the XML doc after this scriptlet has run. The issue is that within this XML doc there is an element that has is using a declared name space that I cannot access.

The top of the rss looks like this

```
<rss xmlns:media="http://namespaceUrl.com/foo/" version="2.0">
```

And the elements attribute that I am trying to access looks like this

```
<channel>
     <item>
          <title>I can access this fine</title>
          <description>I can access this fine</description>
          <!-- however, cannot access this url attribute below-->
          <media:content url="http://www.IwantThisUrl.com" /> 
     </item>
</channel>
```

Now, I have done some testing on many different expressions but I can't get it to work. The most recent attempt at accessing the url attribute was this :

```
<x:set var="url" select="string($newXML/channel/item/*[local-name()='content' and namespace-uri()='http://namespaceUrl.com/foo/']/@url)" />
```

This does not return the expected value of : 'http://namespaceUrl.com/foo/'

Anyone have any suggestions on what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does it return? From the data you showed, it looks like it should return `"http://www.IwantThisUrl.com"`.

Comment: It returns nothing. That is why I am confused :[

Comment: What if you remove the `and namespace-uri()='http://namespaceUrl.com/foo/'` - then does it return something?

Comment: What about `string($newXML/channel/item/*/@url)` - does that return nothing? Trying to determine which part is failing.

Comment: when i removed and namespace-uri()='http://namespaceUrl.com/foo/' nothing happened but when i tried $newXML/channel/item/*/@url it worked!!

Comment: thanks man! should I leave the expression as this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer thanks to LarsH

```
string($newXML/channel/item/*/@url)
```

Comment: To answer your question, I guess leaving it that way is OK, as long as you're confident that other child elements of `<item>` won't have a `url` attribute. I don't know why `local-name() = 'content'` was failing... from what you showed, it looked like it should have worked.